# Purple Screen on every other reboot

Tags: boot

I know simliar questions have been asked but Im experiencing this on every other reboot. If i power down my machine (11.10), I experience a purple screen freeze. However, IF I ctrl,Alt,Delete, then it suddenly works. This happens everytime. Help?

Comment: Can you install "pastebinit" (sudo apt-get install pastebinit) and post the result of "cat /var/log/syslog | pastebinit"?

Comment: Everyone, I have done a clean install to isolate the issue. It only occurs after I install mdadm and edit the fstab to mount my internal raid. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you check /var/log/syslog to see if you find any errors when it tries to umount the devices?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).